# Hibernate Many to Many relationship data insertion?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa, jackson2

My project contains a Card Entity and a User Entity and there is many to many relationships between them. When inserting a user object to card object it doesn't insert the data in the user_card table in the database.

//Controller

```
    @PostMapping(value = "create")
public Card create( @RequestBody JSONObject data){
    Card card = new Card();
    String name =(String) data.get("name");
    Long columnId = Long.valueOf((Integer)data.get("columnId"));
    Long ownerId = Long.valueOf((Integer)data.get("ownerId"));
    Integer  cardOrder = Integer.valueOf((Integer)data.get("cardOrder"));
    String lastDate =(String) data.get("lastDate");
    String description =(String) data.get("description");
    String assignedUsersId= (String)(data.get("assignedUsers"));
    String[] assignedUsersIdArray=assignedUsersId.split(",");
    List<User> assignedUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<assignedUsersIdArray.length  ;i++){
        String id = assignedUsersIdArray[i];
        if(!id.equals("")) {
            assignedUsers.add(userService.getOne(Long.parseLong(id)));
        }
    }

    card.setName(name);
    card.setColumnId(columnId);
    card.setOwnerId(ownerId);
    card.setCardOrder(cardOrder);
    card.setLastDate(lastDate);
    card.setDescription(description);
    card.setUsers(assignedUsers);

    return cardService.save(card);
}
```

//User Entity

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_card",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userid")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="cardid")}
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("users")
private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Card> getCards() {
    return cards;
}
```

//Card Entity

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cards")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("cards")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
//    @JsonManagedReference

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    for(User user : users){
        this.users.add(user);
    }


}
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move `cascade` to card entity. Since you expect insertion to cards trigger insert into user, not other way.